# How to show Factories for when specific User has logged in

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, tankauth

How do I add an factory to any of my logged in users? I'm using Tank_auth and I made an account 'admin' 
I also made a table called 'factoryusers'.

I want to add a factory to a specific user using joins.

My table structure:

```
users
-----
id
username
email
...
...

factories
---------
idfactories
factoryname
adress
...
...

factoryusers
------------
idfactoryusers
idusers
idfactories
```

I tried to join these tables and show the records from the factoryusers table.

My controller function:

```
$data['userbedrijf'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijvenusers();
(translation to english: $data['userfactory'] = $this->factory_model->factoryusers();)
```

My model:

```
function bedrijvenusers()
{
    $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijfusers.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven');
    $this->db->join('users', 'bedrijfusers.idusers = users.id');
    $result = $this->db->get('bedrijfusers', 1);
    return $result->result();
}
```

My views:

```
    <h4>Gebruikergegevens:</h4>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Gebruikersnaam:</label> <?= $this->tank_auth->get_username(); ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Emailadres:</label> <?= $user_data->email; ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Laatste Login:</label> <?= date ("d-M-Y H:i:s",strtotime($user_data->last_login)); ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Account aangemaakt:</label> <?= date ("d-M-Y H:m:s",strtotime($user_data->created)); ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Laatst aangepast:</label> <?= date ("d-M-Y H:i:s",strtotime($user_data->modified)); ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">is admin:</label> <?= $user_data->is_admin; ?></p>
    <hr>
    <h4>Bedrijfsgegevens:</h4>
    <? foreach($userbedrijf as $row){ ?>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Bedrijf_id:</label> <?= $row->idbedrijven; ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Bedrijfsnaam:</label> <?= $row->Bedrijfsnaam; ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Adres:</label> <?= $row->Adres; ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Postcode:</label> <?= $row->Postcode; ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Plaats:</label> <?= $row->Plaats; ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Telefoonnummer:</label> <?= $row->Telefoonnummer; ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Website:</label> <?= $row->Website; ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Email:</label> <?= $row->Email; ?></p>
        <p class="field"><label class="field">Profiel:</label> <?= $row->Profiel; ?></p>
    <?}?>
```

What's wrong with my joins? it shows me factories. but for each user the factory is the same. even when i have multiple factoryuser rows in my database with different user id's and factory id's

Comment: It's not quite clear, but try using left joins.

Comment: when i login as 'admin' my factory name = lauwersdesign. but when i login as 'keessonnema' my factory name is also lauwersdesign. there's no difference between the factories. even when i join. maybe i''m doing it wrong?

Comment: The question isn't quite clear, you are using dutch and englisch together and even i (i am dutch) get confused

Comment: Have you tried getting only the factories for the current user by specifying the userid to the model function and implementing the where clause in the query?

Comment: how do you mean that? @Shomz

Comment: @This_is_me it's a bit tricky to explain too. i did the best i could. but it's really simple. the factory is the same for each user even if either the userid or factoryid is different

Comment: well, this way you're getting all the factories for all the users, see my answer

Comment: I can't add text to that document @This_is_me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not quite clear, but this should get you the factories for the specified user, try it.
I kept your original Dutch/English names.

```
function bedrijvenuser($user_id)
{
    $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijfusers.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven', 'left');
    $this->db->join('users', 'bedrijfusers.idusers = users.id');
    return $this->db->get_where('bedrijfusers', array('idusers' => $user_id))->result();
}
```

Comment: hmm getting a blank page. that's not good. let's see what the problem is.

Comment: I changed the function name - `$data['userbedrijf'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijvenuser($user_id);`

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: user_id
Filename: controllers/members.php
Line Number: 11

Comment: how? i am logged in. so that could not be the problem

Comment: well you need to keep the id somewhere, probably in the session

Comment: use the function above and in your controller call the function like this: $data['userbedrijf'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijvenusers($this->session->userdata('user_id'));